# another way to suggest combobox item

Tags: c#

Is there any way to let combobox suggest elements which not only start with combobox text?

I mean even if the combobox text has space between it's characters,
for example if combobox has these items

- hello
- hi
- hellothere

when we try to type "he" or "h e" or "h    e", the combobox would suggest **hello** and **hellothere**

Comment: You need to provide more detail about your environment - winforms, wpf, asp

Answer (score 0):

Check out the AjaxToolkit Autocomplete Extender. It is very easy to use and you have 100% control over how it behaves.
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[ACO_NOPREFIXFILTERING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762479(VS.85).aspx) is not supported until Windows Vista. Windows Forms does not support this flag.

Answer (score 0):

I used Drew Wilson's excellent jQuery autosuggest plugin recently. You simply provide a textbox on your page and then attach the plugin when the document loads.

I implemented the lookup against a .net webservice which took the user input and returned a JSON response of the results.

Check it out here:
[jquery autosuggest](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)